# How generate a Jmeter Dashboard Report from distributed test (merge data)

Tags: jmeter

I read at the end of "14.2.1 Requirements" in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html:

> When using JMeter distributed mode with multiple jmeter-server instances, ensure you add in your Thread Groups something that uniquely identifies ThreadGroup for every JVM, example:
>
> ```
> ThreadXXX_${__P(JVM_ID)}
> ```
>
> where you pass a different JVM_ID property for each jmeter-server through:
>
> ```
> -JJVM_ID=i
> ```
>
> where i varies between 1 and the number of jmeter-server you are using.

I did it and now I have N data file, one for each node involved in my test. How can I merge this data file in one single report?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To merge it, concat all files in one.

Then use as per [doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only):

> jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>

Ensure you use same user.properties/jmeter.properties as during test.

Comment: Hi, any feedback on answer? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Comment: I use the Concurrent Thread Group by Blazemeter and not the regular one. Where do I add this property then?

Answer (score 0):

To add to UBIK LOAD PACK answer, simple concatenation (Linux `cat`) resulted in error:

> An error occurred: Error while processing samples:Consumer failed with
>   message :Could not parse timeStamp

That is because each file have header and having header in the middle of resulting file is not good. So to merge e.g. on linux (tail -n +2 skips first line):

```
cp file1.jtl all.jtl
tail -n +2 file2.jtl >> all.jtl
tail -n +2 file3.jtl >> all.jtl
...
```

Then

```
jmeter -g all.jtl -o <Path to output folder>
```